# Return.cumulative of multiple time series (xts object, R)

Tags: r, finance, quantmod, performanceanalytics

I have a large number of time series stored in an xts-object. They are the daily price percentage changes of a variety of US mutual funds.

What I would like to get is the cumulative return of each individual time series as shown in the picture below:

[image: simplified Excel illustration]

The `Return.cumulative` function seems to work well, when I only use it on one time series in the xts-object:
`> Return.cumulative(as.numeric(returns_2006$2729), geometric = TRUE)`

But it does not work, when I try to use it on all time series using an apply function:
`> apply(returns_2006, 2, Return.cumulative(as.numeric(), geometric = TRUE))`

> Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
>     'Return.cumulative(as.numeric(), geometric = TRUE)' is not a function, character or symbol

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Do not provide input as images.  Show output of `dput(x)`.  See [mcve].

Comment: I suspect, the problem is with syntax of `apply()`. Try `apply(X = returns_2006, 2, FUN = function(Z) Return.cumulative(as.numeric(Z), geometric = TRUE))`

Comment: @Ekatef: Thank you for the hint. Yes, you were correct about the syntax!

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: thank you for the message. sorry, will do better next time.